# How to know the routes that a user has visited in a SPA with Vue & Vue Router

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I'd like to know all the routes a user has visited. Do Vue Router (v4) or some Browser API exposes this information?

Why I need this information?

I need to distinguish when a user enters the site for the first time or not. When a user which is logged in tries to enter the *login* page, I redirect him/her to *home* page only if the numbers of routes the user has visited is *0* (first time enter). On the other hand, if a user has visited some routes, I cancel the navigation (stays in the current page).

Here is the pseudocode of what I'm trying to achieve:

```js
router.beforeEach((to) => {
    if (to.name === 'login' && userStore.uid.length) {
      if ( determineNumbersOfRoutesUserHasVisited() ) {
        return false
      }
      return { name: 'home' }
    }

    if (to.name !== 'login' && !userStore.uid.length) {
      return { name: 'ingresar' }
    }
  })
```

Above `userStore.uid.length` is an ID. If that ID has something, the user is logged in. Also, `determineNumbersOfRoutesUserHasVisited()` is not implemented yet, It's just pseudocode.

Comment: Pinia or Vuex with persistence plugin. It's not specific to a router at all.

Comment: With the help of Vuex persistance, you can maintain all the routes visited by the user, that way you would have all the details including number of pages visited by the user along with which routes are visited by the user. As soon as user visits a page you store that page in your Vuex store along with route details.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use the `from` argument of `router.beforeEach()` for that. Something like:

```
router.beforeEach((to, from) => {
   if (to.name === ‘login’ && !from.name) {
       /// first time, since from is empty
   } else if (to.name === ‘login’) {
       return false; /// Cancel navigation
   }
   next();
})
```

[See docs here.](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#global-before-guards) I think that you should name all your routes, otherwise name will be empty also in other cases when testing `from.name`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It's a good solution, but not all routes have a `name` in my case.